# Hyphenated and non-hyphenated words that are homophones?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, homophones

We know of many cases where hyphens are necessary to distinguish a compound word (*man-eating*) from a pair of separate words (*man* and *eating*). But are there any cases where a hyphenated word has a different meaning than a like-sounding, non-hyphenated word? (Note that this excludes examples like *coop* and *co-op,* because they are not homophones.)

The only possibility I can think of would be in constructs such as *pro-test* (meaning "in favor of tests") versus the noun *protest.* Any other examples, contrived or otherwise?

EDIT: A colleague of mine came up with a better one: *run-down* (adj.) versus *rundown* (n.).

Comment: _Out-caste_ is often, but not always, written with a hyphen and is homophonous with _outcast_. There’s also the e at the end to distinguish them, though.